# Borrar imagen de una carpeta cuando se cierra archivo PHP desde la web

Tags: php

tengo un formulario que contiene un input file, el formulario genera un PDF,al generar el PDF inserto la imagen seleccionada a una carpeta para poder mostrarla en el PDF.
Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando cierro o recargo la pagina del PDF borre la imagen que seleccione de la carpeta para que la carpeta no este llena de imágenes no requeridas.

(No se que codigo podria mostrar asi que muestro el formulario y el PDF generado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Es posible hacer esto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final del archivo `php` que genera tu **pdf** utiliza la función `unlink(ruta)`, para cuando se ejecute esta función tu imagen ya estará cargada, así que no habrá ningún problema.